# I am trying to make a random name generator using a switch

Tags: generator

This is a project i am working on seperate from school, but is for a school project. i am attempting to make a name generator from a list of set names. I believe i am on the right track, although could be completely off. I am stuck where i am with a few questions.

1. How to make the loop pause itself after each name
2. How to prevent the same name from being generated multiple times
3. How to take it from the BlueJ program i am using to an executable file to run on a computer without BlueJ installed.

any help is appreciated

The code i have is as follows

```
import java.util.*;

class otherNamePicker
{
    static CinReader myRead = new CinReader();
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Scanner readinput = new Scanner(System.in);
        Random myRand = new Random();
        String enterkey = "next name";
        System.out.print(enterkey);
        boolean nextName = true;
    while( nextName )
    {
        int names = myRand.nextInt(8)+1;
        enterkey = readinput.nextLine();
        switch(names)
        {
            case 1:
            System.out.println("JonYoung");
            break;
            case 2:
            System.out.println("SeanWorthington");
            break;
            case 3:
            System.out.println("Katie");
            break;
            case 4:
            System.out.println("Cole");
            break;
            case 5:
            System.out.println("Nico");
            break;
            case 6:
            System.out.println("Mari");
            break;
            case 7:
            System.out.println("Sean");
            break;
            case 8:
            System.out.println("Anthony");
            break;
            //each case being a student's name
        }

    }
}
```

}

Comment: i forgot to mention, the CinReader you see was made by a teacher at my school. it shouldnt matter too much if your code/help does not apply to CinReader as it is fairly all-encompasing

Comment: you could use an array to simplify the code.. String[] names = {"JonYoung", "SeanWorthington", "Katie"} ...